# Rename Multiple Worksheets using List Comprehension

Tags: excel, openpyxl

I am using Python 3.9.4 with openpyxl.
I have an Excel Workbook with 4 Worksheets.
I have written some code to rename the Worksheets that work.

```
names = ['Ja', 'Ro', 'Ra', 'El']
idx = 0
for w_sheet in w_book:
        w_sheet.title = names[idx]
        idx += 1
```

I would like to convert this to List Comprehension and have written the following code (which does not work).

```
names = ['Ja', 'Ro', 'Ra', 'El']
[w_book._sheets[i].title for i in names]
```

I am getting the Error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How can I reference the list of names?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to do this inside a list comprehension: these should, in general, **not** be used for flow control.

The code, as it stands is also error prone as it depends upon an implicit ordering of the worksheets. In general, you should probably use a mapping that explicitly maps one sheet name to another.

But, if you just want to use a list, then the simplest approach is to use `zip`

```py
for sheet, name in zip(w_book, names):
    sheet.title = name
```

This can be adapted for a mapping

```py
names = {"foo": "Ja", "baz": "Ro", "bar": "Ra", "bop": "El"}

for old, new in names.items():
    wb[old].title = new
```